# R-continuity of step function

Tags: continuity

Let us define a function $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ by

$$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if $xy\le 0$,} \\
   0 & \text{if $xy>0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Does limit of $f$ as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$ exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ you can find points $(x,y)$ with $xy>0$ as well as points with $xy\le 0$. Hence $f$ takes values $0$ and $1$ in every neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and is not continuous by the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

For $t>0$ we have $f(t,t)=0$ and $f(t,-t)=1$. Conclusion ?